# Error: One of the provided types for building the Schema is missing a name

Tags: node.js, graphql, node-modules

[This is my app.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gilvZ.png)

[This is my schema.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mtqnh.png)

[I am facing this error don't know to resolve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjAbe.png)

Comment: @Prathamesh More

Comment: It would be nice if you'll provide code examples instead of screenshots

Answer (score 0):

In your schema.js, the `BookType` object is unused. Within the `RootQuery` fields object, the type property should not be within the double-quotes. Undo it. It should be something like this. Hopefully, it will help. [How to set type property within a graphql object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3s1R.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'RootQueryType',
  fields: {
    book: {
      type: BookType,
      args: {
        id: { type: GraphQLString },
      },
      resolve(parent, args) {
       
        return _.find(books, { id: args.id });
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).